# Reaction of alkenes (localised π bond) with nitrating mixture

Tags: organic-chemistry, nitro-compounds

The nitrating mixture for the nitration of benzene contains many strong electrophiles (e.g $\ce{H2SO4}$, $\ce{NO2+}$). All of these could, presumably, add across the π bond in a molecule containing a localised π bond. Do these additions occur and if so what is the major product?

Comment: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01499a029 not sure about H2SO4/HNO3